# Multiprocessing with secure SSL socket

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, ssl, multiprocessing

I'm trying to use multiprocess with a secure SSL socket.
I'm using python 3.
On the server the code looks like this:

```
server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_socket.bind((IP, PORT))
server_socket.listen(5)
client_socket, client_address = server_socket.accept()
...
actions = {}
secure_socket = ssl.wrap_socket(client_socket, server_side=True, 
ca_certs="client.pem", certfile="server.pem", keyfile="server.key", 
cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED, ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
actions[secure_socket] = multiprocessing.Process(target=myfunc, args=(arg1, 
arg2))
action[secure_socket].start()
```

The error I'm getting is:
OSError: [WinError 10038] An operation was attemped on something that is not a  socket

What can I do?

Thank you,
AgentsOfShield.

Comment: Does the ellipsis include `client_socket = server_socket.accept()` ?

Comment: yes.
It works without the multiprocessing.

Comment: Where are you getting the error from exactly? On which statement? How does `myfunc()` access the `secure_socket` that was created for it?

Comment: myfunc() is getting few arguments, one of them is the secure_socket.
When I'm trying to rum myfunc(secure_socket, arg2...) it is working, but when I use the multiprocessing module I get the error message. It is not entering myfunc() at all.